# Why does my for loop with if else clause run so slow?

Tags: python

**TL,DR**:
I'm trying to understand why the below for loop is incredibly slow, taking hours to run on a dataset of 160K entries.

I have a working solution using a function and .apply(), but I want to understand why my homegrown solution is so bad. I'm obviously a huge beginner with Python:

```
popular_or_not = []
counter = 0
for id in df['id']:
    if df['popularity'][df['id'] == id].values == 0:
        popular_or_not.append(0)
    else:
        popular_or_not.append(1)
    counter += 1

df['popular_or_not'] = popular_or_not
df
```

**In more detail:**

I'm currently learning Python for data science, and I'm looking at this dataset on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/yamaerenay/spotify-dataset-19212020-160k-tracks

I'm interesting in predicting/modelling the popularity score. It is **not** normally distributed:

```
plt.bar(df['popularity'].value_counts().index, df['popularity'].value_counts().values)
```

[image]

I would like to add a column, to say whether a track is popular or not, with popular tracks being those that get a score of 5 and above and unpopular being the others.

I have tried the following solution, but it runs incredibly slowly, and I'm not sure why. It runs fine on a very small subset, but would take a few hours to run on the full dataset:

```
popular_or_not = []
counter = 0
for id in df['id']:
    if df['popularity'][df['id'] == id].values == 0:
        popular_or_not.append(0)
    else:
        popular_or_not.append(1)
    counter += 1

df['popular_or_not'] = popular_or_not
df
```

This alternative solution works fine:

```
def check_popularity(score):
    if score > 5:
        return 1
    else:
        #pdb.set_trace()
        return 0
df['popularity'].apply(check_popularity).value_counts()
df['popular_or_not'] = df['popularity'].apply(check_popularity)
```

I think understanding why my first solution doesn't work might be an important part of my Python learning.

Comment: Hint: think about what the computer have to do when the expression `df['id'] == id` is computed. Now think about how many times it have to compute that.

Comment: As a rule of thumb one should avoid directly coding loops in python. There are more pythonic ways of applying a function to all the elements of a set

Comment: It looks like you are using a Pandas dataframe. Python loops are not very fast, and iterating on a pandas dataframe with Python loops is specially slooooow. But pandas offer a number of tools and methods to process a whole column in a single instruction at C speed. This is called *vectorization* by Pandas and numpy fellows.

Comment: Remark: don't override Python's built-in `id`.

Comment: I presume it's the dictionary key lookup as @user202729 hinted.  If you really want to spend time testing performance it may be worth investigating whether it is better to eliminating branching within the loop by replacing the `if` with something like `popular_or_not.append(int(bool(df['popularity'][df['id'] == id].values)))`.   Edit: Assuming you've first fixed the `df['id'] == id` that is.

Comment: Thanks all! So if I get this correctly, I think the reason my solution works is that I'm using ".apply()", which I assume is part of the "tools and methods to process a whole column in a single instruction at C speed" mentioned by @SergeBallesta? And that checking df['id'] == id 160k times in a loop is very slow?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your comments. I'm going to summarize them below as an answer to my question, but please feel free to jump in if anything is incorrect:

The reason my initial for loop was so slow is that I was checking df['id'] == id 160k times. This is typically a very slow operation.

For this type of operation, instead of iterating over a pandas dataframe thousands of times, it's always a good idea to think of applying vectorization - a bunch of tools and methods to process a whole column in a single instruction at C speed. This is what I did with the following code:

```
def check_popularity(score):
    if score > 5:
        return 1
    else:
        #pdb.set_trace()
        return 0
df['popularity'].apply(check_popularity).value_counts()
df['popular_or_not'] = df['popularity'].apply(check_popularity)
```

By using .apply and a pre-defined function. I get the same result, but in seconds instead of in hours.